# Why do two codes look the same, but one does not work ? Python linked list data structure

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

Thanks for reading the question in advance.

I`m studying linked list data structure through Python.  Below two methods push(),  push1() trouble me.

class Node(object):

```
def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.next = None

def __repr__(self):
    nval = self.value and self.next.value or None
    return f"[{self.value}:{repr(nval)}]"
```

class LinkedListController(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.begin = None

# Appends new value at the end of the list
def push(self, obj):
    if not self.begin:
        self.begin = Node(obj)
    else:
        n = self.begin
        while n.next :
            n = n.next
        n.next = Node(obj)

def push1(self, obj):
    if not self.begin:
        self.begin = Node(obj)
    else:
        while self.begin.next:
            self.begin = self.begin.next
        self.begin.next = Node(obj)

# Counts the number of elements in the list
def count(self):
    current_node = self.begin
    count = 0

    while current_node:
        count = count + 1
        current_node = current_node.next
    return count
```

Below is the test code:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from data_structure.single_linked_list_without_endnode import LinkedListController as node_controller
```

class TestLinkedList(TestCase):

```
def test_push(self):
    colors = node_controller()
    colors.push("Pathalon Blue")
    self.assertEquals(colors.count(), 1)

    colors.push("Ultramarine Blue")
    self.assertEquals(colors.count(), 2)

    colors.push("Blaring Sun")
    self.assertEquals(colors.count(), 3)

    animals = node_controller()
    animals.push1("Dog")
    self.assertEquals(animals.count(), 1)

    animals.push1("Cat")
    self.assertEquals(animals.count(), 2)

    animals.push1("Cow")
    self.assertEquals(animals.count(), 3)
```

1. The only difference between push() and push1() is reference 'n', other than that I see the same logic but why push1() does not work ?

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\Dell\projects\data_structure\tests\test_single_linked_list_without_endnode.py", line 24, in test_push
   self.assertEquals(animals.count(), 3)
   AssertionError: 2 != 3
2. In the first push method,`n.next = Node(obj)` is just assigning to reference data 'n', not to `self.begin`.  And I think `self.begin` should be still None since we did not do anything like `self.begin.next = Node(obj)`, but the test is working fine.  How..?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

push1() does not work because you are actually changing the self.begin.
In case of push(), you create new object and give it only the reference to self.begin, and then changing this reference to another object (next), not changing the attribute itself, so that self.begin will stay the first element after the operation (and after push1() self.begin is not the first element, but the second last one).

Comment: Hello, thanks for explanation. Now I got why push1() does not work, that it is constantly redefining self.begin.  But what I still don`t understand is how ''n.next = Node(obj)'' assigns to ''self.begin.next''.   When I do, for instance, "x=10  -> y = 20 -> y=x -> y=30"  and the result of x is still 10.   We assigned to n.next,  but how it actually assigned to self.begin.next ?

Answer (score 0):

In the first push method, it keeps following the linked list starting from your `self.begin` element until it reaches the last element in the linked list, yes it doesn't always directly link your `self.begin` to your new element, but that's how linked list is as a data structure.

In the `push1()` method you keep changing the your base element in the linked list by redefining `self.begin` in each iteration, thus your linked list will lose some of its elements, consider the case where you have 3 -- > 5 --> 6 as a linked list and you use `push1()` to add element 8 for instance, what it will do is that in the first iteration it redefines `self.begin` so it becomes 5 and your linked list becomes 5-->6, then in the next iteration it become only the element 6, then it appends your new element so it becomes 6 --> 8, and that's why the error says `2!=3`, because `push1()` will always result in having a linked list of length 2